# Can an Email get image Url's from a localhost server?

Tags: html, image, email, model-view-controller

Okay let me explain that a little better.
I have a mvc project with a html page and some images and have set up a smtp server to send an email.
When i debug the webpage i get the localhost url. (Localhost:51180)
The Email i try to send looks like this: (simplified version):

```
<html>
<body>
<img alt="img" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />*Working
<img alt='img' src='localhost:51180/Images/img.png'/> *not working
</body>
</html>
```

My problem is that the second pic doesn't work. (if i copy past the url in my web browser while the project is running i can see its the right path). Is it because the website is running local on my computer and the email cant get access to it? or something else? 
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things to try..

#### #1

Try changing the url to `http://localhost:51180/Images/img.png`. you should have the protocol in there (`http`) but i'm not sure you can do this...

#### #2

Use base 64 encoding of the image to embed it.  e.g.:

```
<img src="base64;==asdlfnlansl;34n5ljl5jslj5;hl;sh5j..." />
```

Comment: Alright feeling  a little stupid now, but it worked! I tried the first option and it worked like a charm. Thank You!

Comment: awesome!  so glad it helped

Comment: @Flipsanta please tell how I will use the first option for loading the image. please

Comment: @sircapsalot Can you tell me how to use first option

Comment: As @sircapsalot said, you have to write the following:
<img alt="img" src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" />*Working
<img alt='img' src='http://localhost:51180/Images/img.png'/> *not working
By adding the http protocol before the localhost.

Comment: @Flipsanta but in mycase when I will inspect the `img` element then  then it will show me like `<img alt="something" src="/home/path/of/image.png">` but when I mouse hover the inspected element `img` tag then it will show me in tooltip like `https://localhost:8080/api/v1/image/path.png` then How will now I remove the `http` in this case?

Comment: @Puneet I believe in this case you have to manually type the https://localhost in the image tag, so you have something like: 
`<img alt="something" src="https://localhost:8080/home/path/of/image.png">`

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's a security measure to prevent web sites from accessing/executing anything on your local computer without your permission.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you won't be able to get an image from the local host as it is not always running. You will only be able to get URLS from the Web or if you have stored the image locally within your workspace.